# angular v5.1.0 HttpClient not set header content-type : application/json

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am trying to set header for post api as application.json

```
let options: { headers?: {'Content-Type':'application/json'} }
```

but not set.

Comment: @MarkHim Please don't add disrespectful useless comments like "Code Formatting". Give a direct answer.

Answer (score 21):

To define the content-type with the new **HttpClient** class you need to:

1. Import from `@angular/common/http` (and NOT from `@angular/http` which is currently marked as deprecated)

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

2. Inject the `HttpClient` on the constructor:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

3. Define a private fields `headers` to define the content-type desired and  `options` to prepare the object you will use on the call:

```js
private options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };
```

4. Use it inside your method:

```js
this.http.post('your target url', yourBodyObject, this.options)
```

where `'your target url'` and `yourBodyObject` are used only as example and need to be replaced with your real data.

Answer (score 9):

There is a section on this in the Angular Documentation - probably added quite recently:

```js
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

TypeScript was giving me warnings when I tried to add a response type to httpOptions using the above format, so I use the following successfully:

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/text'
        });

return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text', headers })
```

Docs [link](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)

Answer (score 3):

Check this,

```
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
```

and

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});     
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
```

for Http call.

Comment: The import you provided is for "Http" and not for "HttpClient" class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code here=>

```
let header = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can define the Request headers by creating new **HttpHeaders** object.

HttpHeaders object is **immutable** by nature. So set the all the header details in the same line.

```
getUser(name: string, age: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('name', name).set('age', age);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', 'my token');

    return this.http
      .get(`${endPoint}/user`, {
        params,
        headers
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
public _funName( _params ): Observable<void> {
    const headers = new Headers( { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }  // set your header);
    /* The option withCredentials: true in the code bellow is used with the CORS variables, that is when the REST functions are on another server then Node.js and the Angular2 development application. */

    const options = new RequestOptions( { headers: headers, withCredentials: true } );

    return this.http.post( _yourLink, _params, options )
    .map( this.extractData )
    .catch( this.handleError );
}



public extractData( res: Response ) {
    const body = res.json();
    // const body = res;
    return body || {};
}

public handleError( error: Response | any ) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if ( error instanceof Response ) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify( body );
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error( errMsg );
    return Observable.throw( errMsg );
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This example is for "Http" class, not "HttpClient"

Answer (score 0):

```
let hdr = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
let options = { headers: hdr };
this.httpClient.post(url, payloadData, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP code snippet:

```
let options: { headers?: {'Content-Type':'application/json'} }
```

is defining an options variable of *type* `{ headers?: {'Content-Type':'application/json'} }`, which is valid but not what you want. Change the `:` to a `=` to make it an *assignment*, and removed the `?`, which is not valid for assignments. This is legal, closest to what the OP was attempting, and should work:

```
let options = { headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'} };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `http.put()` then use following code and receiving json/plain text:

```
const httpOpt = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain'
  })
};

this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/bookapi/api/book/'+id, JSON.stringify(requestObj), httpOpt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get user details inside user.service.ts

**Imports:**

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
```

**Declaring variables inside class:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
protected options = {headers: this.httpHeaders,
    search:{}
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

/**
 * getting user details
 * @returns {Observable<any>}
 */
getUser(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('userApi/').catch(err => this.errorHandler(err));
}

/**
 *
 * @param error
 * @returns {any}
 */
errorHandler(error: any): any {
    if (error.status < 400) {
        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
    }
  }
}
```